# 3D animated cartoon where the main character is a tree-like teenager and the lead main character is an eagle humanoid

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It’s a 3d animated cartoon I watched a long time ago.

The main character is a tree humanoid that has something on his hand that makes him turn into a giant version of himself. He has to go find other characters like him, one being an eagle prince that’s kinda edgy with the same item on his hand.

Later on in the show their world gets reset by the antagonist and all the people they knew were turned into monsters that worked for the antagonist. The Mc has to find the other MCs and finds the eagle kid, who is very scared which collides with his usual edgy tone. The antagonist was the brother of the wizard-like character that told the main characters that they needed to stop the antagonist.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "a long time ago?"  5 years?  10?  30?

Comment: Was this a movie or a series?

Comment: It was a series

Comment: I believe it was close to 10 years ago